# Read "_t" field from Mongo DB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

In the situation:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Child), typeof(Sibling))]
public class Parent { ... }

public class Child : Parent { ... }

public class Sibling : Parent { ... }
```

Assuming that 3 classes are saved in the same collection, is it possible to read the `_t` field generated from MongoDB using a collection based on `Parent` class (`database.GetCollection<Parent>`)?

NOTE: I tried to put string[] array inside the `Parent` class, but the field _t returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/), you can filter like this:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("_t", "Cat");
```

You can also use LINQ `OfType<Type>` to filter a list to only one type, or you can test the C# object type to determine what to do.

I don't know that you can "read" the strings directly or not, but the type information is available in C# as well so I don't see how you need it.

Comment: I need to check if a sub collection (based in a bunch of ID's) has the same subtypes, but you gave an idea. I will query using `ofType<T>` and check if the length of the sub collection are the same of the ID array. Thank you!